# Sum of chi-square test statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, chi-squared-test

If I have $n$ test statistics $S_1, \ldots, S_n$, such that $S_i \sim \chi_1^2$, is it true (as it happens with random variables) that $\sum_{i = 1}^n S_i \sim \chi_n^2$?

Comment: This is the basis of Fisher's method for combining $p$-values where he transforms them into a $\chi^2_2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test statistics are random variables.

So just like with any other $\chi^2$ random variables -- *as long as the $S_i$ are independent* -- their sum is distributed as $\chi^2$ with df equal to the sum of the individual dfs.

(I presume that you intend them to be distributed as chi-squared under the null.)